# A program that types out a board containing characters

Tags: c++, puzzle

I found a simple task on a programming discord channel and as a newbie I can not seem to solve it.

> The program should use a subprogram that takes width, height, char_1 and char_2 as parameters and the main program should handle texts and inputs only. You could assume that the user doesn't put a width greater than 26 and a height greater than 100.
>
> ```
> Input height and width: 5 4
> Input characters your program should consist of: H S
> 1 HSHS
> 2 HSHS
> 3 HSHS
> 4 HSHS
> 5 HSHS
>   ABCD
> ```
>
> ```
> Input height and width: 3 7
> Input characters your program should consist of: / !
> 1 /!/!/!/
> 2 !/!/!/!
> 3 /!/!/!/
>   ABCDEFG
> ```

I can only come up with a solution where it types out height.

How do I solve this? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Here's my start:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void print_board(int const width,
                int const  height,
                char const char_1,
                char const char_2)
{
    for (int i {1}; i <= height; ++i)
    {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
}
             
int main()
{
    int width {};
    int height {};
    char char_1 {};
    char char_2 {};

    cout << "Enter width and height: ";
    cin >> width >> height;
    cout << endl << "Enter characters: ";
    cin >> char_1 >> char_2;
    cout << endl;

    print_board(width, height, char_1, char_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you need a nested `for` loop:  `for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row) { for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; ++column) { cout << char1 << char2;`

Comment: Random coding puzzles from Youtube videos, web sites, or chat rooms, are random by their nature, and have no built-in learning value, by definition. They're just random conding puzzles, after all. \It would be sample practice programs from a C++ textbook, that are organized, by topic, together with the corresponding chapter that introduces the concepts and C++ fundamentals that the practice programs are crafted to excersize, those would be the best practice programs for a "newbie" if they want to learn C++.

Comment: Oh yea I got it know, didnt think that i could use the "i" variable. I modified your suggestion to 'for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
to match the preferred outputs. Ty I'm going to try to solve this problem now

Comment: @Austin 

Yes since I wanna call-by-value I put const instead of '&'.

Comment: Something like this: https://onlinegdb.com/IoHuYgq7u

Comment: @Austin Yea just realized that :p, ty anyways

Comment: @JerryJeremiah looks promising but what does if "++index%2" do?

Comment: @leun `++index` increments the value of `index`, then `%2` divides that value by 2 and returns the *remainder* of the division. So, when `index` is 0, then `++0=1` and `1%2=1`. When `index` is 1, then `++1=2` and `2%2=0`. So, `index` is being toggled from 0 to 1 to 0 to 1, etc

Comment: Got it thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

For the main board, you need 2 loops - one to print `height` number of rows, and one to print `width` number of characters per row.

You also need another loop after the board to print out a row of `width` number of alphabet letters.

The following works for me:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_board(int const height,
                int const width,
                char const char_1,
                char const char_2)
{
    bool toggle = false;
    size_t length = to_string(height).length();

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(length) << i << ' ';
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
            cout << (toggle ? char_2 : char_1);
            toggle = !toggle;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   

    cout << setw(length+1) << ' ';
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
        cout << char('A'+j);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
             
int main()
{
    int width {};
    int height {};
    char char_1 {};
    char char_2 {};

    cout << "Enter height and width: ";
    cin >> height >> width;
    cout << endl << "Enter characters: ";
    cin >> char_1 >> char_2;
    cout << endl;

    print_board(height, width, char_1, char_2);

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/23pD0K)

Alternatively:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void print_board(int const height,
                int const width,
                char const char_1,
                char const char_2)
{
    const char arr[] = {char_1, char_2};
    int index = 0;

    size_t length = 0;
    if (height < 10)
        length = 1;
    else if (height < 100)
        length = 2;
    else
        length = 3;

    for (int i = 1; i <= height; ++i)
    {
        cout << setw(length) << i << ' ';
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
            cout << arr[index];
            index = (index + 1) % 2;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }   

    cout << setw(length+1) << ' ';
    for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
        cout << char('A'+j);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
             
int main()
{
    int width {};
    int height {};
    char char_1 {};
    char char_2 {};

    cout << "Enter height and width: ";
    cin >> height >> width;
    cout << endl << "Enter characters: ";
    cin >> char_1 >> char_2;
    cout << endl;

    print_board(height, width, char_1, char_2);

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/JT80M7)

Comment: Thank you! I have a hard time understanding some parts of the code though since I havn't come across "len, ?, !"

Comment: The `len` is the number of digits in the value of `height` (there are other way to calculate that), to know how many spaces to print out at the beginning of each row, to keep the board aligned properly. Imagine when `height` is > 9, then there will be some rows with 1 digit, and some with 2 digits. And some with 3 digits if `height` is > 99. The `?:` operator is a quick way to pick between 2 values based on a boolean expression, rather than using an `if..else`. The `!` operator returns the opposite value of a boolean, in this case to swap the value of `toggle` between `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is trying to change the value of `height` which is declared as constant.

That is why your code will not compile, and your compiler, whatever it is, probably told you this.

But fortunately, you don't need to change the value of `height`!

Printing the height is a simple, straight forward for loop, from 1 to the value of height:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

The tricky part in this puzzle would be to actually print the contents of the lines, because as the second example shows, you need to iterate between the two characters continuously, and ***not start every line with the first character***.

But there is a simple trick to do this!
I will explain it but leave the code to you:

1. Put your two characters in a character array.
2. Multiply counters from the two loops to calculate the number of the current character.
3. Use the power of modulus (`%`) to figure out which character should be printed.

Have fun!